# Sending email after State Machine transition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a small expense tracking app using Rails 4.1. When a user submits the expense request, it's state is marked as pending by default. The admin has to approve the request. I'm using state_machine gem to do this.

I would like to send an email after a request is approved or rejected and I have tried the following model methods:

```
state_machine initial: :pending do
        state :pending
        state :approved
        state :rejected
        #after_transition :on => :approved do |expense, transition|
            #expense.send_expense_approved_email
        #end

        #after_transition :on => :rejected do |expense, transition|
            #expense.send_expense_approved_email
        #end
         after_transition :on => :approved, :do => :send_expense_approved_email
         after_transition :on => :rejected, :do => :send_expense_declined_email


        event :approved do
            transition [:pending, :rejected] => :approved
        end

        event :rejected do
            transition [:pending, :approved] => :rejected
        end
    end

    def expense_amount
        items.to_a.sum { |item| item.amount }
    end

    def send_expense_approved_email
        ExpenseMailer.expense_approved(expense).deliver
    end

    def send_expense_declined_email
        ExpenseMailer.expense_declined(expense).deliver
    end
end
```

While the states transition successfully, I'm unable to trigger emails. I have tested out the mailers in controller actions and they are sent out fine. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

These model methods didn't work. So, used if and else statements to check the state and then trigger the emails in the update action. Not sure, if that's the Rails way, but, it's working.