# Trouble updating nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a small expense tracking app using Rails 4.1. When a user submits the expense request, it's state is marked as pending by default. The admin has to approve the request. I'm using state_machine gem to do this.

Comments are added from the expense show page using a nested_form_for like this:

```
<%= nested_form_for (@expense) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :state %><br />
        <%= f.collection_select :state, @expense.state_transitions, :event, :human_to_name, :include_blank => @expense.human_state_name, class: "form-control" %>
       </div>
       <%= f.fields_for :comments, @expense.comments.build do |comment| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= comment.label :comment%>
          <%= comment.text_area :comment, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

The controller looks like:

```
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @expense = Expense.new
        @item = @expense.items.build
        @comment = @expense.comments.build
    end

    def show
        @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])
        @items = Item.where(:expense_id => @expense.id)
    end

    def update
        @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])
        if @expense.update(expense_params)
            if @expense.state == "approved"
                ExpenseMailer.expense_approved(@expense).deliver
                flash[:notice] = "Expense Report Updated"
                redirect_to expenses_path
            elsif  @expense.state = "rejected"
                ExpenseMailer.expense_declined(@expense).deliver
                flash[:notice] = "Expense Report Updated"
                redirect_to expenses_path
            end
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private
    def expense_params
        params.require(:expense).permit(:claim, :department_id, :expense_type_id, :expense_attachment, :state, :notes, items_attributes: [:id, :description, :amount, :issue_date, :_destroy], comments_attributes:[:id, :comment, :expense_id])
    end
```

The problem is, if I add a comment without changing the state from the dropdown, I get the 'state is invalid' error and the edit page is shown. I can get past this by simply hitting the update button. But, the comments aren't created. On the other hand, if I change the state and add a comment, comments are shown without any issue.

The params value for that is:

```
Started PATCH "/expenses/14" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-15 13:31:40 +0530
Processing by ExpensesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MAEL2UYzos76NV6/eumHkXcpR2ge09wm6eOGQ+eEGCA=", "expense"=>{"state"=>"", "comments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"comment"=>"vv"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"14"}
```

The expense model with state machine looks like:

```
state_machine initial: :pending do
        state :pending
        state :approved
        state :rejected

        event :approved do
            transition [:pending, :rejected] => :approved
        end
        event :rejected do
            transition [:pending, :approved] => :rejected
        end
   end
```

Guess I'm making some mistake when it comes to building the comment attributes. Can someone let me know where I have to make changes?

**Logger info for rejection:**

```
Started GET "/expenses/17" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-15 16:22:43 +0530
Processing by ExpensesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"17"}
  [1m[35mExpense Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "expenses".* FROM "expenses"  WHERE "expenses"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
  [1m[36mItem Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."expense_id" = ?[0m  [["expense_id", 17]]
  [1m[35mComment Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."expense_id" = ?  [["expense_id", 17]]
  Rendered expenses/show.html.erb within layouts/application (16.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 45ms (Views: 42.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started PATCH "/expenses/17" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-15 16:22:53 +0530
Processing by ExpensesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MAEL2UYzos76NV6/eumHkXcpR2ge09wm6eOGQ+eEGCA=", "expense"=>{"state"=>"rejected", "comments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"comment"=>"checking logger for rejected!"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"17"}
  [1m[36mExpense Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "expenses".* FROM "expenses"  WHERE "expenses"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 17]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (8.1ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "expenses" SET "state" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "expenses"."id" = 17[0m  [["state", "rejected"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-15 10:52:53.030676"]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "comments" ("comment", "created_at", "expense_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["comment", "checking logger for rejected!"], ["created_at", "2014-08-15 10:52:53.040889"], ["expense_id", 17], ["updated_at", "2014-08-15 10:52:53.040889"]]
  [1m[36m (4.2ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/expenses
Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 12.8ms)
```

**Logger info for approval:**

```
Started GET "/expenses/16" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-15 16:22:30 +0530
Processing by ExpensesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"16"}
  [1m[35mExpense Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "expenses".* FROM "expenses"  WHERE "expenses"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
  [1m[36mItem Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."expense_id" = ?[0m  [["expense_id", 16]]
  [1m[35mComment Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."expense_id" = ?  [["expense_id", 16]]
  Rendered expenses/show.html.erb within layouts/application (167.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 244ms (Views: 213.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started PATCH "/expenses/16" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-15 16:22:41 +0530
Processing by ExpensesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MAEL2UYzos76NV6/eumHkXcpR2ge09wm6eOGQ+eEGCA=", "expense"=>{"state"=>"approved", "comments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"comment"=>"checking logger!"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"16"}
  [1m[36mExpense Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "expenses".* FROM "expenses"  WHERE "expenses"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 16]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "expenses" SET "state" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "expenses"."id" = 16[0m  [["state", "approved"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-15 10:52:41.604580"]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "comments" ("comment", "created_at", "expense_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["comment", "checking logger!"], ["created_at", "2014-08-15 10:52:41.607555"], ["expense_id", 16], ["updated_at", "2014-08-15 10:52:41.607555"]]
  [1m[36m (4.0ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/expenses
Completed 302 Found in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)
```

Comment: I've tried re indenting your code, check if its correct

Comment: By the way, `state_machine` is not as readily maintained as `aasm_state` - https://github.com/aasm/aasm -- work in VERY similar ways, except the latter is updated much more regularly

Comment: Where is your `state` attribute in your strong params method?

Comment: @RichPeck I'm using a fork of state_machine that's actively maintained. The state attribute is there in strong params. It's fifth in the list.

Comment: Try having `@comment = @expense.comments.build` in your `update` method too. As you're not creating associated comments for @expense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *why* you're getting an error, but I'll give you some ideas for the [`state_machine`](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)  / [`aasm`](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) gems

--

**State Machines**

Since Rails is [*object-orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), you have to appreciate how these [*state machine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) gems work - they are an extrapolation of the electronics method of setting up a "state machine" (to predicate finite "states" within a circuit):

[image]

What I'm trying to demonstrate with this is that by including a `state machine` in your application, you're actually indicating the *state* of an object (it's **not** just another attribute)

Currently, you're treating the `state` attribute of your `Comment` model as an attribute, when it can be treated as an object in itself

--

**Object**

Notice this functionality from the State Machine repo:

[image]

Notice how that has nothing to do with the *state* attribute?

I think you'd be better treating the `state` method as what it is - a way to influence the `state_machine` itself. I would do that in several ways:

> 1. Set the state "default" state in the state_machine declaration
> 2. Validate the *state* object using OOP principles

```
#app/models/expense.rb
Class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
   state_machine :state, :initial => :pending do #-> sets the state to "pending" unless specified otherwise
   end
end

#app/controllers/expenses_controller.rb
Class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
   def update
      if @expense.approved?
          ...
      end
   end
end
```

--

**Fix**

In regards to your being unable to create a comment, I think the problem will be two-fold

Firstly, you're *building* your comments within the view. Apart from anything, this is bad practice (against MVC) - you'll be best building the associated objects inside your `model`:

```
#app/models/expense.rb
Class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.build id
      expense = (id.present?) self.find id : self.new
      expense.comments.build
      return expense
   end
end
```

This allows you to perform the following:

```
#app/controllers/expenses_controller.rb
Class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @expense = Expense.build
   end

   def edit
      @expense = Expense.build params[:id]
   end
end
```

This will basically give your nested `comments` form the pre-built nested objects required to fire the form for the edit & new methods (so you don't need to call `@expense.comments.build` in your view)

In regards to the non-saving functionality - I would certainly look at how you're saving the `state` attribute. **I suspect it will be down to you not passing the attribute correctly** (IE that you're using an incorrect value for the `state` param upon default submission)

I would recommend using the following:

> 1. Investigate your params from the "default" update
> 2. Does the `state` attribute match your model definition of the attributes?
> 3. If it does not, that will be your problem

--

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the update

Okay, so the problem seems to be that the `state` value is not being passed if it's default. I think the way to fix this will be to [set a `default` value for the `collection_select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175053/rails-collection-select-default-option):

- Remove `:include_blank => @expense.human_state_name`
- Replace with `<%= f.collection_select :state, @expense.state_transitions, :event, :human_to_name, { selected: @expense.human_state_name}, class: "form-control" %>`

**Update 2**

Since `state_machine` gives you the ability to track & fire instance methods after a successful transition, you may wish to do the following:

```
#app/models/expense.rb
Class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
    state_machine :state, :initial => :pending do
        state :pending
        state :approved
        state :rejected

        event :approve do
            transition [:pending, :rejected] => :approved
        end
        event :reject do
            transition [:pending, :approved] => :rejected
        end

        after_transition :on => :approved, :do => :send_approval_email
        after_transition :on => :rejected, :do => :send_rejection_email

        def send_approval_email 
           ExpenseMailer.expense_approved(self).deliver #-> might need to call outide of state_machine block
        end

        def send_rejection_email 
          ExpenseMailer.expense_declined(self).deliver
        end

    end
end
```

This will give you the ability to perform the following:

```
#app/controllers/expenses_controller.rb
Class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
   def update
        @expense = Expense.find params[:id]
        if @expense.update(expense_params)
            flash[:notice] = "Expense Report Updated"
            redirect_to expenses_path
        end
   end
end
```

By the way, you need to change your "events" to have different names to your "states". As per my object-oriented references above, you need to be able to call the likes of `@object.approve` etc

Comment: @rick-peck thanks for a brilliant answer. I have embraced the controller methods as you have suggested and I'm gonna spend sometime to understand your suggestions about state machines in details. The state attribute in model is :state. Per your advice, I looked at the params when submitting only a comment without a state change and the value of state is empty. How can I make it to retain the original state?

Comment: Updated answer for you in light of params. Seems your `state` attribute is blank on submit

Comment: the comments are now getting saved. However, now the state drop down shows only one value in the drop down after setting the default. For example, if the previous status is originally "approved" the drop down in the show page shows "rejected" and vice versa.

Comment: Hmm okay, and you want it to save all of the states? Where do the states come from? From my knowledge, they are manually defined, right? Do you have a method to define them?

Comment: I've updated the code with the expense model. The states are defined in there.I would like the admin to approve a previously rejected expense after the employee gives a valid reason. So, I'll need all the states.

Comment: Why don't you create a method in your `Expense` model with all the states in there - `def self.states ["pending", "approved", "rejected"] end` - this way you can call the method like this: `Expense.states` to populate your drop down?

Comment: The model method works. However, when I add a comment to a previously rejected or approved expense, the respective email is triggered. Here's the code I used in the form '<%= f.select :state, Expense.states, :include_blank => false, class: "form-control" %>'

Comment: What would trigger the email? If it's rejected?

Comment: It depends. Let's say the state of an expense is approved and I go in and add a comment, without altering its state. In that case, it sends the approved mail again. In the same vein, if the previous state is rejected and I just add a comment, a rejected email is sent. Currently, expense.approved? and expense.rejected? conditions ensure sending the email.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what you're saying. I think the problem is that you're calling the email when you update the Expense. It should be when you change the state -- which can be done in the model. Let me write an update for you

Comment: Updated - might need to tweak it somewhat

Comment: I used the model methods and the emails aren't sent. Actually, I had tried something like this already and couldn't get it to work couple of days ago and asked a question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285786/sending-email-after-state-machine-transition

Comment: Hmmmmmm very interesting. Can you try putting a Rails.logger.info("test") in each of those methods to see if that fires? If so, we know it's a problem with the email method call; else it will be an issue with the transitions

Comment: Please find the logger info pasted in the question. I haven't tried Rails.logger before. So, sorry if I didn't paste the correct info. Kindly let me know if I need to look for something else in the log

Comment: Hmm looks like the methods aren't firing - let me have a look into this

Comment: please do. Trying to get past this one for a few days now.

Comment: So, I tried all popular state machines - SM, assm, transition, workflow etc. None of the model methods triggered. So,  scrapped them all. Added a current_state to the expense table and started saving the state value. Wrote a conditional loop that checked if state == current state and in such a case no email would be sent. Thanks a ton for your efforts. You spent close to a half day figuring this out for me. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hey thanks for the update! Sorry about not getting back to you - I had a thought about what you were saying, and I think that you'll probably have to invoke the state machine event itself (`object.approve`) to fire the transition event too. Without adding further complication, your implementation might be best serving your app for now¬

Comment: I think since I couldn't get any of the state machine working, I guess I'm not invoking the triggers properly. Ideally, where would I have to invoke something like expense.approve in the controller action or in the model?